# Need assistance in understanding the code I wrote

Tags: python

```
def alarmNoise(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as infile:
        first_line = infile.readline() #Reads just the first line
        rem_lines = infile.readlines() #Reads all remaining lines in doc
        fin_nos = Volume(eval(first_line)) #Calling a prior made class

        for line in rem_lines:
            if line[0] == 'U':
                fin_nos.up(eval(line[1]))
            elif line[0] == 'D':
                fin_nos.down(eval(line[1]))
        return fin_nos
```

This is Python. Okay, the point of this project is to create a function that helps you turn up or down a radio that is playing. The file's first line has where the radio noise is currently on last time you turned the car off (1,2,10, etc), and all following lines are adjustments made on the next ride (up 5, down 2, etc)

I wrote this code in conjunction with a class I made to keep the radio within the correct parameters. I've been trial and error-ing it tonight and understand most of it, but one thing makes little sense. It passed a doc test, and I'm unsure why.

The line in question is

rem_lines = infile.readlines() #Reads all remaining lines in doc

The point of this line should be to make sure all remaining lines, excluding the first one are documented for. But...wouldn't this account for the first line as well (which is first_line, btw). Because I don't explicitly split the first line from the rem line, isn't it still accounted for here?

That also extends to my for loop. I want to iterate over each individual rem line, 
to adjust the noise accordingly (if it goes U up or D down). I have a split to make sure the lines are separated (i.e. U 5 = up by 5). But, isn't this also reading the first line as well because I didn't make the distinction that it is not to be included in rem lines?

That's a bit long-winded. But, I'm trying to understand why rem_lines is not accounting for first_line in my for loop and in its definition. To my knowledge, readlines reads the whole text document and accounts each line as an individual character. All first line is to me is a starting point, an accumulator. So, can someone sort of walk me through what's going on in this relationship?

Comment: All stream objects have a notion of "current position" (which you can sometimes adjust using `stream.seek`, as long as the underlying stream itself is seek-able). The `readline` function reads one line from the current position, which advances the current position. The `readlines` function reads multiple lines, which advances the current position. Each function *starts* from the current position. If you did not use `seek` to move that position, each one starts from wherever the last one left off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a file, python internally creates a pointer which points to the location in the file where you want to read from.

So when you first open the file for reading the pointer points to the start of the file.

readline() reads the current line pointed to and moves the pointer to the next line

readlines() reads all files on or after the one pointed to and moves the pointer to the end of the file.

So when you first call readline() the pointer moves from the start of the file to the start of the second line. Then when you call readlines() the pointer moves from the start of the second line to the end of the file.

Comment: Okay - so to confirm, because I used my first_line function first, anything afterward would automatically begin at the second line? So, let's say I just had rem_lines and no first_line, it would begin at the top?

Comment: yes exactly. Likewise if you had two calls to readline and then called readlines it would take from the third line on

Comment: readline() moves the pointer one line down. readlines() moves from the current position to the end

Answer (score 0):

A file object keeps track of till where it has read so far.
When you call any of the read methods on the file object, it internally advances a pointer till where it has read so far.
There is a way you can manipulate these pointers using the `seek()` and `tell()` methods of file object.
`tell()` gives you the current position of this file pointer 
Using `seek()`, you can manipulate the position of this pointer.

`infile.seek(n, 0)` advances n bytes from the beginning of the file
`infile.seek(n, 1)` advances n bytes from the current position of the file.
`infile.seek(-n, 2)` moves n bytes backwards from the end.

An alternative approach you can follow is:

```
def alarmNoise(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines() #Read all the lines
        first_line = lines[0] #Get the first line

        fin_nos = Volume(eval(first_line)) #Calling a prior made class

        for i in range(1, len(lines)):
            if lines[i] == 'U':
                fin_nos.up(eval(lines[i]))
            elif lines[i] == 'D':
                fin_nos.down(eval(lines[i]))
        return fin_nos
```